# how to do 'run to cursor' in gdb command line

Tags: debugging, gdb

Most debuggers with GUI have a useful function `run to cursor`. Is there any similar way of doing this in gdb?

I'm talking about assembly mode debugging (without source code).

For example, it currently break at: `0x400000`, I'd like to run to `0x400100`,  there're lots of instructions between them. To do this, I have to:

1. set breakpoint at `0x400100` with `b *0x400100`,
2. continue with `c`
3. delete breakpoint with `d ...`

It is lots of typing, and I need to do this frequently. Any simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for either "until" or "advance" command.

Details in GDB manual chapter [Continuing and Stepping](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html#Continuing-and-Stepping).

If stopping on frame exit is problematic, you can still use tbreak, which sets temporary breakpoint, which is automatically deleted once it is hit.